# JavaScript && notation in Object Creation

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

My question is on the following expression:

```
var prototype = Object.create(extend && extend.prototype);
```

I think it's creating the prototype object inheriting the extend object.  And `extend && extend.prototype` is checking to see if extend exists and extend.prototype exists.  If either one doesn't exist, prototype will be a object without superclass.  And if both exist, prototype will inherit extend?  How does it know to use `extend.prototype` with `extend && extend.prototype` syntax?

So `var prototype = Object.create(extend && extend.prototype)` and `var prototype = Object.create(extend.prototype)` are the same if both `extend` and `extend.prototype` are there?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't agree that the question is a duplicate, although that answer should help the OP understand this as well...

Comment: @JDB: Only that this question is actually not about `Object.create` at all.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Given that the hearts of the current two answers are "*It will return the last truthy value*" and "*The value of a `&&` operation is the value of the first "falsy" expression, or else the value of the last expression*", and given that the thesis of the accepted answer on my proposed duplicate is "*the Logical AND operator (`&&`) will return the value of the second operand if the first is truthy*" I don't see any substantial difference between the answers here. Granted, the OP asks for specific results based on certain conditions, but those are deducible from the general principle.

Comment: @apsillers: But note the difficulties that this presents.  I don't know where this code is from.  But if `extend` is undefined, then this code will throw an error.  The final question obviously can be answered with a simple "yes", but there's more here.

Comment: This is from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM 54:32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that in JavaScript, unlike other C-heritage languages, the `&&` operator does not (necessarily) have a boolean result. The value of a `&&` operation is the value of the first "falsy" expression, or else the value of the last expression. The *tests* it makes are performed on the coerced-to-boolean values of the subexpressions, but the resulting value is the raw value of whichever subexpression was the last to be evaluated.

This in the evaluation of

```
extend && extend.prototype
```

the resulting value will be either the value of the subexpression `extend` or of the subexpression `extend.prototype`.  If `extend` is `null` or `undefined` or any other "falsy" value, then that value will be the overall result. Otherwise the value will be that of `extend.prototype`.

Note that if `extend` is, for example, a simple object, and specifically one without a property called `prototype`, the overall value may still be `undefined`. It's clear that the intent of the code in the question is to pick the prototype reference of a passed-in constructor function, but it's not "bulletproof" code.